# Google cloud. NVIDIA T4 was available for days but not available for last 72+ hours

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I used to use NVIDIA GPU T4 in Google Cloud zone europe-central2-b before, but now it is not available since about 4 days ago. Is that normal for such a long time, or does it happen that google removes GPU's? I have already transferred my disk from other region where NVIDIA became unavailable long term and moving data to other region costs money. I would like to avoid that. So if GPU is not available for 4 day, should I keep trying or should I give up?

Comment: See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-resource-availability  but the generic recommendation is *"try in a different zone"*. I can only assume but it is a safe bet that with the ongoing AI hype supply simply can't keep up with demand and even GCP can be temporarily sold-out.

Comment: Despite the fact Google sponsors and/or [links](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/stackexchange) to ServerFault, it is **not Google** support. The ServerFault community can only help with [on-topic questions](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) but can't resolve capacity issues, billing issues, [outages](https://status.cloud.google.com/) and similar problems. When you do have [a paid support plan](https://cloud.google.com/support) maybe ask your questions there: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases and they can give you an insider perspective.

Comment: When you are using the GPU, what is the error message that you are having?

Comment: Thanks for responses. I was not asking for the solution, rather about the experience, how long I should wait before giving up. The error I am getting is standard  capacity issue: "The zone 'projects/.../zones/europe-central2-b' does not
  have enough resources available to fulfill the request.  Try a different zone, or
  try again later." But I am not going to migrate to other zone every few days, its expensive. Does anyone know is AWS has similar capacity issues? I have read that never,

Comment: In GCP I have seen this a number of times, in different zones/regions, and with regards to different instance types. I have never seen anything like that with AWS, with which I worked many years. I don't know if there is any max. duration this may last. Probably the most "GCP way" to go about it is to be prepared and switch to another region when this happens. Not an ideal situation, and probably a bit of a surprise, in particular if one comes from AWS or Azure background.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a designated person that processes your account, you may contact them for faster reservation. The other way is you can create [reservations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reservations-overview) on the console to reserve resources that are needed for your workloads. In this way, you can mitigate transferring to another zone/region.

To verify your issue, you can check your logging with error message `ZONE\_RESOURCE\_POOL\_EXHAUSTED` that indicates the resources you request is currently not available on the zone or region.

Additionally, you may read this [thread](https://groups.google.com/g/gce-discussion/c/vlKpp3BlYjA) regarding resources that are not available on a certain region/zone.